# Rails. General advise on creating and updating a model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model

I'm a beginner at web programming. **I want to make the user navigate different questions, each updating an instance of the model Item.**

My plan was to create two links that create this instance, one adding the value "found" and the other the value "lost" to a "Category" parameter. I also wanted this link to redirect to an update form, which will be a search box and a submit button that will edit the parameter "Name" value.

So far, what I managed to do is in my home view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info mb-4 "><%= link_to "I lost something", new_item_path(category: "lost")%> </button>
```

Then on my Item controller,

```
def new
item = Item.new
item.category = params[:category]
item.user = current_user
item.save
end
```

This allowed me to create an instance and get the "lost" value for the :category parameter.

This is my .new view, where I was thinking of placing a search box and a submit button. Right now there is a form.

```
<%= simple_form_for(item) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now, I want to update the same instance with that form and I got completely lost. How do I make this submit button update the instance? Should I call an update action from my ItemsController with the SimpleForm? Anyone help on how to do that?

I hope my question is clear. Maybe there is a more convenient way to do this.

Any help is appreciated, with our without code

Edit: it seems using AJAX is a good way to go for what I want to do

Comment: you don't need to save in new action. just create instance like @item = Item.new(category: params[:category]) and in you view do it like for_for(@item, method: 
 :post) to hit update/create action action on the very same controller.

Comment: you can follow the guide here https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html